# Removing non-significant main effects / interactions

Tags: regression, feature-selection, interaction, multiple-comparisons

I have a hypothesis that my dependent variable (a clinical outcome) is mediated both by main effects and by interactions between them. I want particularly to demonstrate that (or measure whether) the interactions are 'important'. My sample N is quite large (~1,000), and I have 12 independent variables. I know that at least some of these will have significant, main effects, but I don't have strong priors on which ones.

I ran an initial analysis in Matlab with an n-way ANOVA, with all grouping variables as continuous. And I do get some results which could make sense. However, it feels like I'm running too many comparisons even for my sample. I'd like to try to reduce the number in a sensible way.

What I want to do, is:

1. run the analysis with main effects only
2. remove the non-significant main effects3
3. re-run the analysis with just the remaining main effects AND their interactions.

I suppose my intuition here is that I want to stick with the most important variables, and then find out how those interact.

But I'm aware this reasoning may be fallacious. If it is, can someone explain how? I would also much appreciate any alternative suggestions for how to measure the 'importance' of interactions in my data.

Comment: It is not appropriate to use p-values for model selection.  Use subject matter knowledge to pre-specify the model.  If you must, you can do a single chunk test for testing all interactions jointly, and either keep or delete all of them.

Comment: From reading this site, it appears that it's not appropriate to use any 'data driven' method for model selection!! But is that really practical? I want to take a view about which elements of my dependent data are driving the outcome: I'm pretty sure it's not all of them, and certainly not all their interactions, but I'm equally sure it is some of them. Answering this kind of question has to be possible, surely?

Comment: The question is possible, but the answer, using simple approaches you hope to use, is not.  The data don't have enough information to tell you which variables are 'real'.  Bootstrapping the process will expose this.

Comment: Why not just use a lower p value? That would reduce the probability of getting a type 1 error.

Comment: All of the variables are 'real', but not all are equally important. Naturally one can't hope to find the 'true' model just with the data, but one must be able to find some sensible approximation of it. Or indeed at least the best model we can find with the methods and data currently available. While doubtless correct in principle, the idea that we simply cannot answer these questions at all in practice, even allowing room for error, is surely wrong: preposterous even. That being said, I guess I'll look for a more principled heuristic...